# Why has this question been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

Based on the fact that it's a specific problem that applies to many people, could be invaluable to those using MediaMonkey, and has no answer anywhere else I was expecting it to get at least a handful of upvotes, but I definitely wasn't expecting a downvote.

[How do I stop MediaMonkey from forcing itself as the device's default AutoPlay behaviour?](https://superuser.com/questions/1246317/how-do-i-stop-mediamonkey-from-forcing-itself-as-the-devices-default-autoplay-b)

What, if anything, is it lacking?

Comment: Tim Post [lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your question.

Comment: Why do you just expect upvotes?

Comment: @random - Because there's no valid reason to downvote it, and that's how SE works; a valid, well-put question should attract no downvotes. The only thing I can think of is that it was done out of spite but maybe it was a genuine mistake or someone had a bad day. Either way, it shouldn't become normality to expect downvotes on valid questions, as you seem to be implying that it should be.

Comment: You assume people agree your question is well-put or it was well researched.  It could be the subtle hostility, "How do I disable this intrusive default behaviour?", in your question itself.  Take your pick.  As for not providing a comment, people who review posts frequently, can recall past reactions users have had to feedback.  Three of your four questions here at meta.superuse have extremely negative tones to them, all three of them, have tones and statements that indicate there is nothing that can be improved to raise the quality of your questions.  You wanted feedback, it's been provided

Comment: No, the default is no votes. It's not to expect to get upvotes just because

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone felt it lacked research. A few folks apparently get annoyed by quick self answers (which I would add, is silly! Its an excellent way to document odd things). A few folks go "Why is he complaining over a single downvote" and decide to give him another one to complain about. [Tim Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397). Solar Flares, Rick Flairs, [Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj066W64IfWAhUFOI8KHT_GA-MQtwIIJjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJmzuRXLzqKk&usg=AFQjCNFfF4RWdOCN53Nx9LyMyWZs4USKcA)

No one really knows other than the downvoter. Humans are fickle creatures, and unless the downvoter decides to comment, there's no real way to tell.

Comment: Maybe some stupid people just like to randomly downvoting stuff because they're sad, because they're lacking sexual activity, or their tooth is aching... Anyway, I think this site would be much better if downvotes have some sort of reasoning behind.

Comment: Its unlikely to happen - its a commonly requested feature by new users. Simply speaking, non anonymous downvotes could result in revenge downvotes

Comment: It could still be anonymous, just the site could request an explanation (from a list of options or something).